# how to delaty NTPD startup or otherwise fix NTP not starting on boot

Tags: boot, services, ntp

My NTPD does not start properly on boot in that none of my clients can get time from it but when I logon and type

```
systemctl restart ntp
```

it starts working

If I re-boot and logon then attempt to use ntpq and type peer I get the following

```
ntpq> peer
ntpq: read: Connection refusedntpq>
```

So I'm thinking to delay startup would fix this My NTPD version is

> ntpq 4.2.8p4@1.3265-o Wed Jul 12 12:23:43 UTC 2017 (1)

my complete ntp.conf is

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.

pool 0.au.pool.ntp.org iburst
server netservices.wilson.lan

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery


# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

Other info

1. Netservices is a raspberry PI which has similar issues with NTP not
   starting
2. I have tried commenting that server out and it does not fix
   the issue
3. The box has a SSD drive so it boots quickly (3 -4
   seconds)

Comment: Hmmmm, good question.  But I guess you could stop the ntp from loading at startup by removing the shortcut from the `/etc/rc2.d/` folder that is named `S03ntp`.  That file just means that when the system starts in Run Level 2, all applications in that rc2.d folder will start.